# Updating A Single Attribute in Rails from email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

i'm having some issues trying to update an attribute outisde my web app (No route matches [GET] "/admin/justifications/19/approve").

The user should approve or reject a permission from their emails...

admin/justifications_controller.rb

```
class JustificationsController < BaseController
before_action :find_justification

 # PATCH/PUT /admin/justifications/1/approve
def approve
  @justification.approve
  @justification.create_activity :approve, owner: current_user, recipient: @justification.user
  redirect_to request.referer
end

# PATCH/PUT /admin/justifications/1/reject
def reject
  @justification.reject
  @justification.create_activity :reject, owner: current_user, recipient: @justification.user
  redirect_to request.referer
end
```

routes

```
scope :admin, module: :admin do
  resources :justifications, except: :all do
    member do
      patch :approve
      patch :reject
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Tho this works well in my web page, but it breaks when users try to open the generated links sent to their emails.

Is it something im missing here??

Any help would be great. Thnks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `approve` action is only available via `PATCH` or `PUT` and the link you press in your email sends the request via `GET`

There are lots of questions in SO asking how to send a different method than `GET` from the link you send in the email and the answer for that is: It is not possible. You have to open an `GET` action to be accessed from your email links.

Comment: Thank you, i've made a GET method for this only, i'm not sure if this is the right way, but it's working!. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to natively add links which send a `PATCH` request - Rails uses a `data-method` attribute together with some clever javascript to fake `PATCH`, `PUT` and `DELETE` requests.

However this only works if `jquery-ujs` is loaded in the client, which is problematic since many email clients and even webmail clients block emails from running javascript for security reasons.

What you need to do is add a `GET` route.